# when `cargo install cargo-generate` get error:failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index` in my intel mac

Tags: rust-cargo

when  `cargo install cargo-generate` get an error `error: failed to fetch` https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index%60

during carry out this command,i get a warning :`warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): [28] Timeout was reached (Connection timeout after 30004 ms); class=Net (12)`

then give a error:

```
cargo install micro-http
    Updating crates.io index
warning: spurious network error (2 tries remaining): [28] Timeout was reached (Connection timeout after 30004 ms); class=Net (12)
warning: spurious network error (1 tries remaining): [28] Timeout was reached (Connection timeout after 30001 ms); class=Net (12)
error: failed to fetch `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`

Caused by:
  network failure seems to have happened
  if a proxy or similar is necessary `net.git-fetch-with-cli` may help here
  https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#netgit-fetch-with-cli

Caused by:
  [28] Timeout was reached (Connection timeout after 30004 ms); class=Net (12)
```

i can visit github.com ,and i refix my rustup to the newest version;but all these methods do not work, who can help me fix this;

i can use my M1 mac  to fix cargo-generate, who can tell me which aspect i meet,thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I have solve my problem

`git config --list`

lookup my git config ,i find i have set a proxy for git,like this:

proxy='xxxx.xxx'

i carry out `git config unset proxy` to cancel my proxy

then i fix my problem